# Getting NullReferenceException was unhandled

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1415

This is what I entered.  It will build with no errors.  But gives me the null error on:

```
"MySqlConnection = new SqlConnection"(MyConnectionString.ConnectionString);
```

I am using VS2010 C#...

```
MyConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Data Source=sql1;Initial Catalog=DW_screening;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xxxxx;Password=xxxxxx;Write"];
MySqlConnection = new SqlConnection(MyConnectionString.ConnectionString);                    
MySqlConnection.Open();
MessageBox.Show("Connection Opened Successfully");
//MySqlConnection.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to find a connection string *called "Data Source=sql1..." in your settings whereas you want to actually treat that literal value *as* the connection string.

If you really want to hard code your connection string, just use:

```
string connectionString = "Data Source=sql1 [etc]";
MySqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
// etc
```